# How to display a custom signal strength UI when the actual signal strength is empty?

Tags: android, custom-rom

I built my own custom ROM from AOSP Source using Google Cloud Platform. I synced and compiled everything into a flash able zip. Everything works fine except the signal strength keeps flickering (empty cellular signal strength) which I've never seen on any stock ROM. Like this:

[image]

I am very new to compiling custom ROM so I'd like some guide on which files to edit from the files I've synced from source to "fake" the empty cellular signal strength to a minimum signal strength like this.

[image]

Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Why do you want to fake the signal strength ?

Comment: @Hugoy It's just a way for me to kinda make it look like a stock ROM although its not a hugeee difference.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, SystemUI package is the place to start. (frameworks/base/packages/SystemUI).

```
// Android N based.
// Mobile network Signal Strength icons
com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.TelephonyIcons

// Control which icons to be displayed?
com.android.systemui.statusbar.policy.MobileSignalController

// Place holder where signal icon is displayed.
com.android.systemui.statusbar.SignalClusterView
```